# Как настроить в intellij idea автовыравнивание тернарных операторов?

Tags: intellij-idea, настройка

есть код

```
value = условие ? выражение
  : выражение;
```

как настроить автовыравнивание в идее таким образом?

```
value = условие ? выражение
                : выражение;
```